PJSIP: How to display dialled number on touser phone ios swift
`Hi guys, im trying to display dialled number on touser phone, now it was showing the sip registered number in touser phone. but i want to show dialled number.
NOTE: this is voip call, no incoming feature with in the app.
Here is the sample code:
// make call method
void make_call(char* name, char* sip_id, char* sip_server){
    pj_status_t status;
    /* If URL is specified, make call to the URL. */
    char sip_uri[80];
    sprintf(sip_uri, "\"%s\" <sip:%s@%s>",name, sip_id, sip_server);
    pj_str_t uri = pj_str(sip_uri);
    pjsua_call_setting call_set;
    pjsua_call_setting_default(&call_set);
    status = pjsua_call_make_call(account_id, &uri, &call_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
        error_exit("Error making call", status);
}

// registered method
int account_registered(char \*sip_domain, char \*sip_user, char *sip_passwd)
{
pj_status_t status;
/* Add UDP transport. \*/
{
pjsua_transport_config cfg;

        pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.port = 5060;
        status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
        {
            error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    /* Initialization is done, now start pjsua */
    status = pjsua_start();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);
        return 1;
    }
    /* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
    {
        pjsua_acc_config cfg;
    
        //        cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(SIP_DOMAIN);
        
        pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
        char id[60];
        sprintf(id, "sip:%s@%s",sip_user, sip_domain);
        char reg_uri[60];
        sprintf(reg_uri, "sip:%s", sip_domain);
        
        cfg.id = pj_str(id);
        cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(reg_uri);
        cfg.cred_count = 1;
        cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
        cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
        cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(sip_user);
        cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
        cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(sip_passwd);
        
        status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &account_id);
        
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
        {
            error_exit("Error adding account", status);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

please help me, Thanks in advance
